# Console Loggers Multithreaded Concurrence

Tags: c++, logging, boost-log, spdlog

I have the main application that uses boost log to output log to the console and library that uses spdlog to output to the console. Logs come from multiple threads. The question is how can I guarantee that the logs will not  overlap each other

Comment: Use a mutex, unless the library is already thread safe.

Comment: Another option is to queue messages to another thread that performs all of the logging. If the queue requires protection with a mutex, this usually keeps the lock period much shorter than writing to a log file.

Comment: Can you reroute spdlog output to Boost.Log? If not, you will need a way to synchronize spdlog output with Boost.Log output. If spdlog doesn't offer API to do this, you will probably have to patch it.